# Is it possible to adjust the placement of labels in Google Data Studio?

Tags: format, label, position, looker-studio

I'm using a stacked column chart to show numbers of participants in clinical trials each month. Each stack shows two categories of trial, commercial and non-commercial. I can turn labels 'on' or 'off', but is there any way to adjust their position or size? As you can see, the commercial label for May is just about illegible. How can I improve this?
[stacked chart by month](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zzXIF.png)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The label font size can be set:

[image: set font size]

Add a reference line to exceed the y limit of the graph and the label should appear above the bar. (Setting a max value for y axis is also possible)

Comment: Thank you!  Setting a max value on the Y-axis did the trick. I'd been adjusting the plot area up and down but nothing was working.  Great tip.

Comment: Actually... No that doesn't work well, most of the time. I have a dropdown for users to select from 30 categories. When ALL categories are selected, the max Y-Axis value (set to 11,000) works fine.

But many users select only one or two categories, and monthly values may be very small, single digits in some cases, so they are now completely invisible with the Y-axis set to 11,000. That's a worse problem than the one I'm trying to solve.

So the axis needs to remain set to auto. It seems unbelievable that Data Studio doesn't have a label option like "outside end" or "centre".

Comment: @PatRyan, I am sorry to hear that . You could generate a calculted field with `Non-commercial / 10`. Add this field to your bar plot and make the color white. In the Chart Bar plot, this value would be as well show and confuce the user. In the Chart plot you could only activate the display the value of the  `Non-commercial`. To ensure that the graph fits on to the y-axis, add the created field. Would it be an option to switch the two bars.  In our company, there is costomized visualization used for showing many of the bar charts. However this one only allows one metric, but several drilldowns.

Comment: I don't understand enough about Data Studio to attempt (or really understand) what you mean, but I will try it on a "test" report. But switching the bars is a great idea!

I now have Commercial on the bottom and Non-commercial on the top. I also changed the colour scheme and the labels are much more legible. Maybe it won't work in *all* scenarios, but I have tried several combinations and I like it so far.  Thank you!!